kafka connect does not load connectors
I am using the following dockerfile to load mysql connector in my kafka-connect image.
FROM eclipse-temurin
RUN mkdir -p /opt/kafka/bin /opt/kafka/libs /opt/kafka/config /opt/kafka/logs
COPY ./kafka/bin /opt/kafka/bin/
COPY ./kafka/libs /opt/kafka/libs/
COPY ./kafka/config/connect-distributed.properties /opt/kafka/config/
COPY ./kafka/config/connect-log4j.properties /opt/kafka/config/
COPY ./jdbc-source-bulk.json /opt/kafka
RUN mkdir -p /opt/kafka/connectors
COPY ./mysql-connector-j-8.3.0/* /opt/kafka/connectors/
WORKDIR /opt/kafka
EXPOSE 8083
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/connect-distributed.sh","config/connect-distributed.properties"]


I get the following when running the container
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,252] INFO Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli:120)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,304] INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/kafka/connectors/mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,529] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/opt/kafka/connectors/mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:80)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,537] INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/kafka/connectors/build (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,546] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/opt/kafka/connectors/build/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:80)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,546] INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/kafka/connectors/demo (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,554] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/opt/kafka/connectors/demo/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:80)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,554] INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/kafka/connectors/generated (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,562] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/opt/kafka/connectors/generated/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:80)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,563] INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/kafka/connectors/legacy (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,570] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/opt/kafka/connectors/legacy/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:80)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,570] INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/kafka/connectors/main (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,577] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/opt/kafka/connectors/main/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:80)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,578] INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/kafka/connectors/test (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,585] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/opt/kafka/connectors/test/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:80)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,585] INFO Loading plugin from: classpath (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,600] INFO Registered loader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@c387f44 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:80)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,601] INFO Scanning plugins with ServiceLoaderScanner took 297 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:70)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,602] INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/kafka/connectors/mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,913] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/opt/kafka/connectors/mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:80)
[2024-04-21 20:31:45,913] INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/kafka/connectors/build (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)



result of: curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d @jdbc-source-bulk.json 
localhost:8083/connectors/mysql-source-bulk/config
{"error_code":500,"message":"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector', version='3.7.0', encodedVersion=3.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector', version='3.7.0', encodedVersion=3.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector', version='3.7.0', encodedVersion=3.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}"}

Any leads what i am doing wrong here?
tried to load connectors and kafka-connect does not recognize them.

The mysql connector jar is a JDBC driver with no kafka connect plugins. You'll need to separately add Confluent JDBC connector to the plugin path
I'd suggest using Debezium mysql connector image, for example, rather than copying kafka files on your own

The Debezium images are much easier. Thanks!
